# Can I restrict which processes have network access?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

So, Sometimes I connect my PC to a mobile hotspot when the WiFi is down, because it happens often. And whenever I do, all these weird processes chew through my mobile data incredibly fast. Is there a way, in windows 10, to have some rules, that restrict all but a couple processes from having network access?

Here's what I mean by this
[image]

Here is the resource monitor, now under the **Network** tab, we have a panel **Processes with Network Activity**, I only want the **chrome.exe** process to be able to send and receive Bytes, and I want to prevent all other processes from having that ability. Is there a command I can run, or a way to prevent all other processes from having network access, until I grant them access again.

Right now I have to do this **manually** by right clicking the process and hitting **End Process (Tree)** and even then the process starts using the mobile data again after a couple seconds,

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Why not use windows firewall to block all outbound and inbound(all protocol and ports) for those process, you want to block?

Comment: How can I configure windows firewall?

Comment: And I'm not trying to block a specific set of processes, I just want to block them all except google chrome, then when I connect back to WiFi, I'll unblock them. How do I do that?